# How to customise the default error message for empty username on login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

login credentials :

```
{
    "account_id":"",
    "password":"abdu@123"
}
```

response :

```
{
  "account_id": [
    "This field may not be blank."
  ]
}
```

This error comes from rest_framework.fields.CharField. I tried to override it by doing :

```
class MyField(CharField):
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _('Not a valid string.'),
        'blank': _('This field may not be blank changed......'),
        'max_length': _('Ensure this field has no more than {max_length} characters.'),
        'min_length': _('Ensure this field has at least {min_length} characters.'),
    }
```

This doesn't change the error message. My Serializer :

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        ...
        return token

    def validate(self, attrs):
       ... 

        
        data = super(MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
        data.update({"user_id": self.user.account_seq})
        data.update({"account_id": self.user.account_id})
        data.update({"is_migrated": int(self.user.is_migrated)})
        data.update({"role": self.user.authority})
        return data
```

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   ...
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   ...
```

Comment: Can you show your serializer

Comment: I have edited to show the serializer

Comment: Can you show the model that has `account_id` field here?

Comment: edited to show models.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to create your own field. You can just add the `error_messages` attribute like the following.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, error_messages = {
        'blank': '...',
        'null': '...',
        'invalid': '...',
        'max_length': '...'
    })
```

Comment: it is not possible for me to edit the models, why is there no other way ???

Comment: If it is not possible to edit the models, why are you trying to create your own model that derives from `CharField`? I think you can't use that Field in models.py file if it's impossible to edit the models, right?

Comment: The db is provided by my client. I did python manage.py isnpect db to create the models. I can't migrate to change db. I wanted to see if I can change the default error message at serializer level or at least by overriding the fields.py module. Neither of which seems to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do so is as follow

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    account_id = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
.
    def validate(self, attrs):
        errors = dict()
        if attrs['account_id'] == "" or attrs['account_id'] is None:
            errors["account_id"] = "Account ID may not be empty"
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)
        return super().validate(attrs)
```

It will first try to validate with your custom logic and with super() it validate with inbuilt logic. If you catch errors type prior to inbuilt you can provide custom error messages

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

I overrode **init** method of TokenObtainPairSerializer and manually checked if the request is empty and then threw a custom error.

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        acc_id = kwargs.get('data').get("account_id")
        password = kwargs.get('data').get("password")
        if not acc_id:
            raise MyCustomExcpetion(
                detail={"error": "account id cannot be empty"}, status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
            )
        val = super().__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        return val

    ...
```